# Only a single subdomain cannot connect to the server why?

Tags: dnssec, ns-record

I have a lot of subdomains on azrhymes.com,
eg. de.azrhymes.com, es.azrhymes.com, etc. (~20 subdomains)
and all of them work (including some very new ones) 
except ru.azrhymes.com that responds 'we could not connect to server'.
What could've gone wrong?

Details:
I'm behind cloudflare and recently enabled dnssec, using wildcard ssl certificates and tried both * and specific A records - no difference.
I use a standard digital ocean debian droplet server, ru is in AMS3 region.
I don't use any dns zones.
I also purged my local dns cache (`dscacheutil -flushcache && sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`).
(Tested connectivity through google and yandex webmaster)

Update:
ru.azrhymes.com works 1 out of 10 times - roughly.
(I've changed A record ip to a different server, changed back and the problem now went away on my computer and on yandex webmaster, google webmaster still cannot find my sitemap. This does not look too comforting.)

What can I test?

Comment: can you please clarify why downvote?

Comment: Likely because there is no actual in information here to point to a cause.  All one can do is guess. At least some basic things could be tested if you didnt hide the domain names.

Comment: Thanks @yoonix, I've updated my question, uncovering the domain names. Can you please let me know what further details are relevant here?

Comment: Shot in dark, but if it works sometimes and sometimes not it's likely still your DNS. Either not propagated out properly (yet) or had a mistake in it at some point that got propagated previously. Try setting your browser machines DNS server to your Authority servers for given domain. If that works 100%, you just need to wait.

Comment: de.azrhymes.com doesn't resolve to the CloudFlare addresses. Make sure you have an orange cloud for it.

Comment: @bshea ok, I try and figure out how to set my browser's DNS server to my Authority server.

Comment: @MichaelHampton correct, thanks, I forgot to add an A record for de.azrhymes.com, now I've corrected it. (There's a wildcard A record... is it possible that that one can mess up the resolution?)

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs - Normally, if the server in question is a single IP, you just set the IP returned by authority in your clients `/etc/hosts` file. But you are not a single IP. First lookup the authority NS record(s): `dig de.azrhymes.com NS` then use that as the query server: `dig de.azrhymes.com @beth.ns.cloudflare.com` -> The IP returned is what authority is sending out. (Currently, I see 104.27.179.20 and 104.27.178.20). Edit `/etc/resolve.conf` and place both IPs in it - or better: still use `/etc/hosts`, but test the IP's one at a time.

Comment: ^That of course assumes your client is Linux(Deb) or Mac. If Windows, amounts to same. Edit the `hosts` file for an "override" to specified IP. Google: *windows+hosts+file* if you need to.